# How can I reduce the image id/xlink data of my SVGs?

Tags: xml, svg

I recently started using an in-browser animation tool called SpiritApp, it uses SVGs which are altered to change the `<g id` property to `<g spirit-data-id` then the code file is pasted into the body of your HTML file.

I used a tutorial first to get the hang of it (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pggg-W3qS_o&t=212s) which was very straight forward and the SVG wasn't a huge file and was easy to place in the markup. I then used ProCreate to create my design, exported to PSD then AI and saved for screens as an SVG exactly as was taught on the tutorial.

After Brackets crashed a few times opening the SVG file, when it opened I was confused as the image id's were HUGE, I thought I had accidentally minified the file at first but re-saved SVG and it was definitely not minified. I will have to screenshot as there is thousands of lines of code for one layer(!). It seems to be where it declares the `xlink:href`, does anyone know what I am doing wrong? The tutorial showed a very clean formatted SVG file on Brackets, not sure why mine is about 10k longer as it was only 4 layers.

[image: Example of Code]

Comment: 10K isn't bad for four images.  A small image minimum size is usually around 20k to 40k.

Comment: @jdweng, is there any way to reduce this in my code though? I can minimise the lines which helps of course but its annoying if I am trying to work on something as its slowing the program down. Is there a way of referencing it so that I could keep the file separate?

Comment: I ended up referencing using an `object` tag which worked perfectly.